# Vue JS doesn't render inside of Electron app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, electron

I've got an electron app that loads Vue JS 2 from my local machine, however, whatever element I attach my `el` to completely empties the element and replaces the contents with the Vue JS comment, what am I missing?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bulma0.9.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/tv.css">
  </head>
  <body style="background: white;">
    <div id="app>
      {{ message }}
    </div>
    <script src="./assets/js/vue2.6.12.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/tv.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

tv.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#tv',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

This renders nothing, how can I get Vue JS to render?

Answer (score 1):

As Zac already stated, there is a typo in your code. Also there is a missing quote at line 12 (`<div id="app">`). I think you have two possibilities. Either you change the id to tv such as:

```
<div id="tv">...</div>
```

Or, based on Zac's answer, change tv.js to:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code, do you mean to use `#app` instead?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- you
 - without error

tv.js - example
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
message: 'Hello Vue!'
}
})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).